# Image not showing in ASP.net visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am designing a webpage using Visual Studio 2012. When I put the following code in the source

```
<img src="E:\BCA\ASP.Net\Images\Questionnaire.png" />
```

In the design view I can see the image but when I run the page using browser the image is not visible. Sometimes I see a lined rectangle but Image is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use relative path something like

```
<img src="../Images/Questionnaire.png" />
```

or you can use server control like

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="~/images/Questionnaire.png" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be security restrictions in the browser not showing content that is local on disk.

You can use relative path like Amir said in his answer. If you use Razor in MVC and not web forms, you can use `~` directly in the `<img>` tag like this:

```
<img src="~/Images/Questionnaire.png" />
```

The `~` is automatically translated to the web application root.

Comment: Then how can I make my browser to show images from the disk?
And when I use notepad and design a simple html page then I can see the images correctly. The problem is only when I design using visual studio

Comment: Is the image not located under same location as web site?

Comment: The best is to serve everything you want to show as content in a directory that is under the same root as the web site, so you should copy your images into the web application folder. Web sites are usually for serving a site to the public, and those never have access to your disk.

Answer (score 0):

you should give like this

```
<img src="../Images/banner2.jpg" />
```

the "Images" is the folder in your vs where ur image "banner2.jpg is loaded already"